# Correct way to generate idiomatic rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning rails 6 and walking through creating some toy resources. I know in my data model, I want to create a "widget" let's say, but I don't want everything that a scaffold is going to produce, so I'd like to manually generate everything that I know I'll need and nothing more. I started with a simple model. Next I'm trying to generate the controller + views I know I'll need. I ran:

`rails g controller widgets index new show delete`

This ended up creating a router with the following routes:

```
  get 'widgets/index'
  get 'widgets/new'
  get 'widgets/show'
  get 'widgets/delete'
```

I'm surprised by this, I would have expected something similar to the routes that are generated by default with the scaffold:

```
     things GET    /things(.:format)         
            POST   /things(.:format)         
  new_thing GET    /things/new(.:format)     
 edit_thing GET    /things/:id/edit(.:format)
      thing GET    /things/:id(.:format)     
            PATCH  /things/:id(.:format)     
            PUT    /things/:id(.:format)     
            DELETE /things/:id(.:format)
```

Am I using the correct generator command to accomplish what I described? Or is this something that I would just need to manually set up with my routes?

EDIT: I realized the action I'm actually looking for is `:destroy`, and not `:delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails generators are really just for generating the needed files, for anything out of the ordinary you will have to manually change things.

You can add this to your `routes.rb` instead of that list of `GET`s

```rb
resources :widgets, only: [:index, :new, :show, :destroy]
```

Which will produce an output similar to what you have in your question if you do `rails routes` from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal if you don't want to use scaffold, and for some routes they are need to be setup manually like the delete route, it is a delete request not get like the controller is generating (the controller always generate get requests because it expects a corresponding view)

You can use:  `resources :widgets, only: [:index, :new, :show, :destroy]`

this will generate what you want because this is the convention used in rails